# Does this query creator class make sense to you?

Tags: php, sql, class, makefile

I am preparing a simple class. I want to create a query by following a different path. Class below it is a draft. I look forward to your suggestions.

The Cyclomatic Complexity number 4. PHP Mess Detector, PHPCS fixer tools, I have no problems.

My English is not good, I'm sorry.

```
<?php

class test
{

    protected $q = array();
    protected $p = array();

    public function get()
    {
        $new = array();
        foreach ($this->p as $value) {
            $new = array_merge($new, $value);
        }
        $this->p = $new;

        print_r($this->p);

        $query = 'select * from table ';
        foreach ($this->q as $sql) {
            $query .= implode(' ', $sql) . ' ';
        }
        echo $query . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function camelCase($value)
    {
        return strtolower(preg_replace('/(.)([A-Z])/', '$1 $2', $value));
    }
    public function __call($method, $params)
    {

        $clause = $this->camelCase($method);
        $clause = explode(' ', $clause);

        if ($key = array_search('in', $clause)) {
            $clause[$key] = 'in(?)';
        } elseif (isset($clause[2]) && in_array($clause[2], array(
            'or',
            'and'
        ))) {
            $clause[1] = $clause[1] . ' =?';
            $clause[3] = $clause[3] . ' =?';
        } elseif (isset($clause[0]) && $clause[0] == 'limit') {
            $clause[$key] = 'limit ? offset ?';
        } elseif (isset($clause[1]) && $clause[1] != 'by') {
            $clause[1] = $clause[1] . ' =?';
        }

        $this->q[] = $clause;
        $this->p[] = $params;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

The use of the query creator class is as follows.

```
 <?php
 (new test())
    ->orderByIdDesc()
    ->limit(15)
    ->get();

 (new test())
    ->whereIdOrName(6,'foo')
    ->get();

 (new test())
    ->whereIdIsNotNull(10)
    ->get();

 (new test())
    ->whereIdIn(9)
    ->get();

 (new test())
    ->whereIdNotIn(8)
    ->get();
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
)
select * from table order by id desc  limit ? offset ? 
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => foo
)
select * from table where id =? or name =? 
Array
(
    [0] => 10
)
select * from table where id =? is not null 
Array
(
    [0] => 9
)
select * from table where id in(?) 
Array
(
    [0] => 8
)
select * from table where id not in(?)
```

If it does not make sense, you can write why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is question for codereview.

Comment: I did not understand. How?

Comment: Post it here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In terms of responsibility, your class should never echo in a method.

```
public function get()
{
    $new = array();
    foreach ($this->p as $value) {
        $new = array_merge($new, $value);
    }
    $this->p = $new;

    print_r($this->p);

    $query = 'select * from table ';
    foreach($this->q as $sql){
       $query .= implode(' ', $sql) . ' ';
    }
    return $query . PHP_EOL;
}
```

And

```
<?= (new test())
->orderByIdDesc()
->limit(15)
->get();
```

Also, you should have a look at existing libraries rather than inventing and maintaining your own (eloquent for instance).

If you're PHP 5.4+ (which I hope), you could use the short array syntax.

The class could probably be final and with private attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will consider it.

Comment: Forgot to tell you: you can use tools such as PHP Mess Detector, PHPCS fixer and so on. Look at what the cyclomatic complexity is.

Comment: I did not know the tools you gave me. Thank you for your answer. I will examine them.